# How to replace deprecated function in jQuery Mobile - updateHash

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I tried updating from jQuery Mobile Beta 2 to rc1.

Chrome gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'updateHash'

I am using changeHash like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage(page);
$.mobile.updateHash(page, true);
```

The function seems to be removed since  Beta 3. Which function can replace its functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now an argument to the method `$.mobile.changePage()`:

> changeHash (boolean, default: true) Decides if the hash in the location bar should be updated.

So your code should be updated to:

```
$.mobile.changePage(page, { changeHash: true });
```

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/methods.html